# Ambiguity in calculating mean of normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let X be a random variable with distribution $N\left(0,1\right)$

$$\therefore  f_X\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\left(x^2/2\right)}$$

Y be another random variable such that,

$$f_Y\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\left(x - \mu\right)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

and Z is such that,

$$f_Z\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\left(x - \mu\right)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

By location-scale transformation I can write Y as $\sigma X + \mu$.

Simple calculations yield,

$$EX = 0$$
thus,
$$EY = E\left(\sigma X + \mu\right) = \mu$$

and,

$$EZ = \dfrac{EY}{\sigma} = \dfrac{\mu}{\sigma} $$

But $EZ$ should be equal to $\mu$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such random  variable $Y$ since $f_Y$ is not a density function. What is true is $Z$ has same distribution as $\mu +\sigma X$ and $EZ=\mu+\sigma EX=\mu+0=\mu$.

Comment: I agree that Y is not a valid distribution. $f_Y(x)$ is just a scaled version of $f_Z(x)$ which means that EY should be $\mu$. So what is wrong with these following statement,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Y(x) dx = \mu$$ 
$$  \sigma\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Z(x) dx = \mu$$
$$  \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Z(x)  = \dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}$$

Comment: All this analysis of yours makes no sense. Since $f_Y$ does not integrate to $1$ there is no $Y$ with density $f_Y$. If you work with non-existent random variables you can get all kinds of contradictions.  @AkashKarnatak